# HTML5 in IE11 not working properly but good in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have started learning HTML5.The main issue i am facing same things is working in differently in differnt browser/versions.Specially in IE its hard to Work.
Below is my code snippet which is working perfect in chrome but not in IE11.

I have two versions of IE, IE8 and IE11.I want to run the same in different versions in IE and know the trick/Tweak of it.

[image: Left one IE11 and Right one Chrome]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Forms API</title>
    <style>
        label {
            margin-top: 20px;
            display: block;
        }

        input {
            width: 200px;
        }

            input[type=submit] {
                width: auto;
            }

        .col {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" action="NewURL"> 
      <label for="yearsInDev">Number Demo:</label>
            <input type="number" name="MyNuberElement" id="MyNumberElement" />

            <label for="devExperienceRange">Range Demo:</label>
            <input type="range" name="MyRangeElement" id="MyRangeElement"/>

            <label for="bgcolor">Color Demo</label>
            <input type="color" id="MyColorElement" name="MyColorElement" />

            <label for="arrivalDate">Date Demo</label>
            <input type="date" id="MyDateElement" name="MyDateElement" />

            <label id="arrivalTime">Time Demo</label>
            <input type="time" id="MyTimeElement" name="MyTimeElement"/>


            <label for="arrivalDTLocal">DateTime Local Demo</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" id="MyDateTimeLElement" name="MyDateTimeLElement" />

            <label id="arrivalDT">DateTime Demo</label>
            <input type="datetime" id="MyDateTimeElement" name="MyDateTimeElement" />


            <label for="birthMonth">Birth Month</label>
            <input type="month" id="MyMonthElement" name="MyMonthElement" autofocus />

            <label for="vacationWeek">Vacation Week</label>
            <input type="week" id="MyWeekElement" name="MyWeekElement" />

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value" id="MyPlaceHolderControl" 
               name="MyPlaceHolderControl" autocomplete="on" />

        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: **This will never work in IE8**. Now, with that out of the way, most of the more advanced input types are [not supported by any IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). So, I hate to say it, but you have set yourself an impossible goal.

Comment: Have Explained not working with screenshots .Please have a look if you get chance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Thanks for the input. Is there any way to know the limitations for browser to browser , version to version

Comment: Yes, the link I posted.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Thanks . It helped.But not sure why number element also not working as chrome.May be i am new so facing such scratch issues  .

Comment: The number element works fine in Chrome, you won't see the increment icons until you hover over the input.

Comment: @APAD1 - In chrome its good. In fact in chrome everything is good. I am thinking about number element in IE

Comment: As has already been stated, IE does not support these advanced input types. IE10+ does have partial support for a number input, but you will not get the same functionality as you would in other browsers.

Comment: you could use some polyfills: http://html5please.com/#input

Answer (score 0):

when you are dealing with different browsers ,

- either you can use the **reset.css** , which will flush every styling on the browser and you can style everything of your own
- you can use the webkit

> ```
>  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( ... );/* IE8- */
>   width: -ms-linear-gradient(200px); /* IE10+ */
>   width: -webkit-linear-gradient(200px); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
>   width: -o-linear-gradient(200px); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
>   width: -moz-linear-gradient(200px); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
>   width: linear-gradient(200px); /* Standard syntax */
> ```